# Как правильно организовать работу с данными в Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

Сейчас в коде выборка из БД помещается в DataFrame:

```
with self.engine.connect() as conn:
                    query = f"""SELECT ...."""
                    rezult = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

И далее в коде идет обработка и перебор строк (а их там миллионы):

```
df = rezult[УСЛОВИЕ_ВЫБОРКИ_ИЗ_ОБЩЕЙ_ВЫБОРКИ]
df = df.groupby(['name']).agg(
                    list).reset_index().replace([None], np.NaN)
for _, row in df.iterrows():
   ....
```

Соответственно сами вопросы:

1. На сколько это производительно(т.к. невооруженным глазом видно что тут надо обладать не малой памятью для этого)?
2. Правильнее ли будет убрать эти манипуляции из питона и раскидать эти их на операторы Airflow и данные передавать между ними?

Comment: Мы ничего не знаем ни про конфигурацию ваших сервером, ни про используемую базу данных, ни про объем вычислений (под многоточием), ни про ваши требования к производительности. Попробуйте, сравните результаты... На первый взгляд, перенести фильтрацию по условию и группировку в SQL-запрос кажется разумным, хотя даже это нужно проверить на практических данных.

Comment: Если вы делаете `iterrows`, то вы явно неправильно используете `Pandas`. Ну и в целом предпочтительнее делать обработку данных в `SQL`, если они уже там лежат. Если возможностей `SQL` недостаточно, то есть ещё `Spark` для обработки больших данных. В целом, не зная, **что именно** вы дальше делаете с данными, тут сложно что-то конкретное советовать.